# Converting image into varbinary from within a select statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, blob

I have a select statement which is currently returning `ArticleTitle` and `ArticleThumbnail` (this is currently just an image path), now i want to return the bytes of image instead of path, i know this is possible with `openrowset`

I tried with that, for the single image it works and returns the binary data, but i want to return binary data for multiple images, from within the select query. Could anyone tell me how shall i return binary for multiple images from select query.

Here's an example of my select query:

```
select 
    title, thumbnail, 
    (select * from openrowset(BULK, N''' + thumbnail +''', SINGLE_BLOB) as Thumbnail) 
from 
    article 
where 
    isnull(thumbnail, '') <> ''
```

Comment: Do you want to return them as separate columns in a single row in your query?  Or in separate rows?

Comment: Separate column for each row.